# Setting multiple event handlers in one statement

Tags: c#, events, c#-4.0

Having that line:

```
this.button1.Click += this.button2.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

why this line doesn't works

> Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `System.EventHandler`

We need to spare one more line to do this?
But imagine if we got 20 button for that

```
this.button1.Click += this.button(n).Click += MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

I know what you will say:

> You can do a for(each) for each buttons and ...

but what if i need to choose which button I want?

So, why the first line of code doesn't works, and do a such thing exist (wrote differently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to separately add the event handler to each event, and the error message is telling you exactly why. In C#, `this.button2.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Test");` does not return the lambda value, so there is nothing there to add to the `button1.Click` event.

It's also just plain bad style. I had to read the first line twice to realize that you where trying to do. You should never sacrifice clarity in favor of succinctness.

Comment: So, i need to copy-paste a part of the line and change the name of the control, it's ugly but it's for clarity

Comment: I'm honestly struggling to understand what is ugly about assigning an event handler to two separate events on two separate lines. They are logically distinct actions that have only a coincidental relationship in that they use the same event handler. In my mind, you solution is much uglier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hook up three or more buttons to a single event handler (inline or fixed), you will need to put them on separate lines.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

        // OR

        this.button1.Click += (s, a) => ShowMessageBox("Test1");
        this.button2.Click += (s, a) => ShowMessageBox("Test2");
        this.button3.Click += (s, a) => ShowMessageBox("Test3");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello Event World");
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but it's what i wanted to not do, but i think i will need to do it :(

Comment: Understood.  More lines of code, but very readable. (I agree with @Jason Watkins)